# How to change classpath in Scala Worksheet in IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is it possible to alter the classpath when running IDEA Scala Worksheet? No matter what I tried, the classpath seems to be fixed like this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-server.jar
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/util.jar
/Users/huyle/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea14/Scala/lib/scala-library.jar
/Users/huyle/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea14/Scala/lib/scala-nailgun-runner.jar
/Users/huyle/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea14/Scala/lib/compiler-settings.jar
/Users/huyle/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea14/Scala/lib/jps/nailgun.jar
/Users/huyle/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea14/Scala/lib/jps/sbt-interface.jar
/Users/huyle/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea14/Scala/lib/jps/incremental-compiler.jar
/Users/huyle/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea14/Scala/lib/jps/jline.jar
/Users/huyle/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea14/Scala/lib/jps/scala-jps-plugin.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug [SCL-6726](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6726).  I suggest reporting bugs when you find them, or voting for them if they are already reported, so that the Intellij developers can prioritize their (probably massive) work queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a worksheet inside of a sbt project you get all the dependencies of the sbt project on the classpath of the worksheet.

Comment: Tried, doesn't work for me. Scala Console work perfectly, classpath included the build directory. But it is not the same as Scala Worksheet, I always get the same fixed classpath.

Comment: That is my experience.  E.g. i just tried a "hello world"  spark scala worksheet from within a spark sources project. The scala worksheet could not even find org.apache.spark !